# Returning the MD5-hash of all files in a directory to a .txt file with file name

Tags: command-line, find, md5sum

I have a directory of pictures.

I need the MD5-hash of each file in that directory and the name of the file placed into a `.txt` document. This file is to be read at a later time to reference the MD5 and file name together.

**Note:**
I would like this to just pull all directory files with me specifying them.
I have tried playing with `tar` and `find` and I just cannot seem to find a good solution...

This is a directory example:

```
/Desktop/testing
RandomFilename1.png
RandomFilename2.png
RandomFilename3.png
```

The `.txt` output is:

```
RandomFilename1,da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
RandomFilename2,da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
RandomFilename3,da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

I've looked everywhere online with no luck.
This will be on a Linux terminal.

Comment: Do you really want the file names without the extension in the output? If so, what if two file names only differ in their extension?

Comment: See answer by marcolino in particular on yhe linked duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following `bash` command:

```bsh
for file in testing/*; do md5sum $file; done > res.txt
```

Of course you have to adjust the destination directory of `res.txt`.
The result could look similar to this:

```
8b1500ea6fe42927891fd1831bb955ba  testing/Pic1.gif
73f3222889a14411a3b78675ed0bc269  testing/Pic2.gif
c5b18ef1ea1346f13f668a7ead4e4c92  testing/Pic3.gif
```

So the MD5 hash is followed by the filename and path.

Comment: The benefit of this solution is that you can later check the md5's with `md5sum -c res.txt`. I'd also suggest a simple `md5sum *.gif > res.txt` instead of a loop.

Comment: Also, you should move the redirect outside the loop: `for file ... done > res.txt`, instead of opening and closing that file for each run of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, execute `md5sum` and use `sed` or `awk` to transform the output

```bsh
md5sum *.png | sed 's/^\([0-9a-f]\+\) \+\(.\+\)/\2,\1/' >images.md5sums
md5sum *.png | awk '{print $2","$1}' >image.md5sums
```

However, the plain output of `md5sum` is `hash  filename` and is equivalent to your format. Using that standard `md5sum` output format is often more convenient, since you can use it directly with `md5sum -c` to check the hash of the files (after a copy or network transfer). Some other utilities may also expect this particular format.

Answer (score -1):

I have written a small script as per the parameters defined:

```bsh
cd /home/username/Desktop/testing
for F in *
do
    echo "$F", $(md5sum "$F" | sed -e 's/'"$F"'//g')
done
```

Example output:

```
1.txt, c8ef7cca2ceb3f878921b1ff163dbf91
demo, e9470a3c74b32036fa148dfabce70929
File with spaces.txt, c691b3d2fc2678839a9c141b6ee1524e
line.cpp, e0732d2781c6b2b57d413f79f9c1fd28
test, 3734699610e8d322767cf65f90ed43ce
test.cpp, afbe5b90cf002e1eb6df4cf98dfe4c0e
```

**Note:** This script would show the output in terminal. To save it in file you can use `> 1.txt` while executing the file, for e.g.:

```
./test.sh > 1.txt
```

Comment: Nice, although I'd suggest couple improvements.  Use `for F in ./*` instead of plain `*` there. Filenames with leading dashes will be interpreted as flags to command and not filename. I literally had spend 5 minutes figuring out why `for f in *` loop was hanging, and that was because I had `-` file , so expansion made `md5sum  -` read from stdin.  Second,  you could do `echo  "$F", $(md5sum < "$F" |  tr -d '-' )` and that also reduces complexity in  parsing  `md5sum` output.

Comment: What you can also do is `md5sum "$F" | awk '{printf "%s,%s\n",substr($0,length($1)+3),$1 }'` This is just 2 pipelines and should be safe against filenames with spaces.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Yeah you are right. It is unresponsive with filenames starting with special characters. I tried using `./*` instead of simply `*` but I'm getting errors like: `sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to 's'
./test.cpp`. I don't know why. While the second suggestion `echo "$F", $(md5sum < "$F" | tr -d '-' )` is working fine. Again with third suggestion `md5sum "$F" | awk '{printf "%s,%s\n",substr($0,length($1)+3),$1 }'` error is being generated `invalid option` with filenames having `-` in starting.

Comment: @Kulfy It probably complains about the `/` part because `/` is separator in sed, so you're doing something like `sed -e 's/./foobar//g'`. Not a big deal, GNU sed can use different separators so something like `sed -e 's#./test##g'` could work

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thank you for letting me know this. But the output is like `./<filename>, <mda5sum> ./` and sometimes `./<filename>, <mda5sum>`